# Compiling bubblesort error

Tags: java, sorting, compilation

Ok so here is my code bellow, the compiler doesnt show any any error but wheneveri ran it, i get  i get this error "Exception in thread "main"

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
at BubbleSort.bubblesort(BubbleSort.java:18)
at BubbleSort.main(BubbleSort.java:8)"
```

----------------------------Code---------------------------------------------------

```
public class BubbleSort {

   static int[] numbers = { 5, 8, 14, 1, 5678 };

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       BubbleSort bb= new BubbleSort();
       bb.bubblesort(numbers);
       bb.printArray(numbers);



   }
   static  void bubblesort(int[] arr){
       int temp;
       for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
           for(int j=0;j<(arr.length-i);j++){
               if(arr[j]>=arr[j+1]){


                   temp=arr[j];
                   arr[j]=arr[j+1];
                   arr[j+1]=temp;
                   }

           }
       }
   }
   public void printArray(int[] arr){

       for(int i:arr){
       System.out.println(i);
       }

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks all of you for the explanation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change you second condition to be -1:

```
for(int j=0;j<(arr.length-i -1);j++){
```

Reason for iteration i =0 it will go iterating till arr.length + 1 (here if(arr[j]>=arr[j+1]){)

Also (not to do with bug but warning) you defined bublesort as static and accessing via instance. You could change that?

Comment: You also defined printArray() as instance. It could easily be a static method and then you don't need the instance of BubbleSort at all.

Answer (score 0):

This error means you are accessing an index that is out of bounds of the array. The error happens on the line:

```
if(arr[j]>=arr[j+1])
```

Note how for `i=0`, `j` varies from 0 to `arr.length-1`. Therefore j+1 varies from 1 to `arr.length`.  `arr[arr.length]` throws the out of bounds error.

Answer (score 0):

In the first run of your outer loop i=0; therefore arr.length-i = array.length = 5. On the last iteration of your inner loop j = 4. Therefore j+1 = 5 and when you try to reference the element of array with index 5 you are getting the exception.